# paperclip S3 network error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

in ruby on rails, using S3 with paperclip for staging and production mode. its working fine.
for development mode. I'm using local storage.

in development mode when i turned off the wifi or disconnect from internet. I'm getting this error. if i connect to internet. it works fine and pull the images/files from local path.

**I'm not sure why in development mode, the code still checks the s3,** while it works on the local storage very fine when connected to internet.

**AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError: AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError
gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:318:in `return_or_raise'**